# How to use phonegap with windows phone 8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I'm using phonegap for making an html5 game on my windowsphone. I can start the game but I couldn't touch the "start" button to start the game. I tested my html code on my iphone, my lap, my web browser successfully. I tested with phonegap for iphone successfully. However, I don't know how to make it run ok on my windows phone 8.

[image: i can run game but cant touch the "start" button of game]

[image]

[image: my game run ok on the other client!!]

I share my source code [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=E7AC57738247F8D6!107&authkey=!AKathNcxGtZhGws) if you want to test/check it.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I check your code, and I didn't see a call for the cordova.js. I develop an windows phone app too with phonegap and I have to call the corodva.js first in my html file.

Comment: i 've just delete that code for that for checking, althought i add cordova.js to my html code, i get the same result. still cant not klick the start button. you can check this/